# Setting geo-coordinates for DXF file to EPSG:4326 CRS in GeoPandas not working

Tags: geopandas, dxf

I am trying to following this [article](https://hatarilabs.com/ih-en/spatial-manipulation-autocad-dxf-file-with-python3-and-geopandas) (that uses 'EPSG:32719)as an example - to geo-reference my DXF file to lat/long coordinates with the EPSG:4326 CRS. The x and y after the translation are not even close to the target:

`Long: -115.9910775 and Lat: 36.741635`

The total bounds of the DXF file are:

`array([ 15.39999008, 581.27550693, 135.79997635, 594.62499905])`

and I am applying the following translation after setting the CRS to set the lower left-hand corner (origin) to the target location:

```
%matplotlib inline
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd

gpd.crs = "epsg:4326"
plano = gpd.read_file('input-file.dxf')
plano.plot()

plano.total_bounds

geometryScaled = plano.scale(1.0,1.0,1,origin=(0,0,0))
geometryTranslated = geometryScaled.translate(-115.9910775,36.741635,0)
plano = gpd.GeoDataFrame(plano, geometry=geometryTranslated)
plano.crs = "epsg:4326"
plano.plot()

plano.total_bounds
```

Output:

`array([-216.58216492,  654.75841164,  -96.18217865,  668.10826905])`

Notice the total bounds of the translated geometry (minx, miny, maxx, maxy) is not what I expect. I would expect that the minx = -115.9910775 and miny = 36.741635. I would expect a CRS of EPSG:4326 to be within the bounds of:

`bounds: (-180.0, -90.0, 180.0, 90.0)`

Comment: You need to know the CRS of the source coordinates _[ 15.39999008, 581.27550693, 135.79997635, 594.62499905]_ to be able to transform them.

Comment: I guess I am not understanding because the DXF (Autocad file) is not geocoded yet and therefore does not have a projection system. The source coordinates are merely the DXF coordinate space. The mentioned article does the same unless I am missing something?

Comment: The coordinates expressed in DXF geometries (eg, the points coordinates) must be referenced in some way with the Earth to be able to transform them to another reference system. The relation between the geometries coordinates and a place in the Earth is the CRS. DXF files doesn't have a CRS defined, but you need to know it to be able to transform them.

Comment: In the mentioned tutorial, the CRS of the DXF was supposed to be a translated and scaled version of a UTM zone projection, the parameters of scale and translation were estimated measuring objects in a map. But you are assuming your CRS as geograhic coordinates (EPSG:4326) without any scale but a translation of (-115.9910775,36.741635,0), and that is not possible because the extent of the DXF geometries is greater than latitude 90 degrees (581.27550693 is not a possible latitude in degrees format).

Comment: So it sounds like I need to scale my DXF to a 4326 zone projection before I can translate it - correct?

Comment: Planar coordinates can't be scaled to geographic ones. It sounds to me like you need to georeference the DXF file using a projected coordinates system. Then you can reproject it to 4326 with other modules.

Comment: How do I "georeference the DXF file using a projected coordinates system?" The above article does not do any georeferencing (that I can see) before taking the DXF file into geopanadas. The coordinates of the DXF is simply the coordinate system with Autocad and is not georeferenced. I believe that is the point of the tutorial. But correct me if I am wrong and misunderstanding.

Comment: Here is how the tutorial describes itself: "This tutorial shows the procedure to open a DXF file in Python pandas, perform scale and translation to place the spatial features on their original position, filter unwanted objects on the layout view and export results to QGIS3 as shapefile." In fact, at 1:31 into the tutorial, he says that the DXF file is not georeferenced.

Comment: It is georeferencing the drawing estimating the scale and translation in a map, and the map is shown in a projected coordinates system.